# Why is the corresponding statement not executed even if echo empty($location) prints out 1

Tags: php, switch-statement, case, boolean-expression

```
echo empty($location);
switch($location){
    case (empty($location)):
expression 1;
    break;
    case ($location%10000==0):
expression 2;
    break;
    case ($location%100==0):
expression 3;
    break;
    default:
    expression 4;
    break;

}
```

When I echo empty($location), it prints out 1, why is expression 1 not executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using switch statements properly. The way they work is to compare each case value against the initial `switch` value.

In your case, let's pretend `$location = null`;

```
echo empty($location);    // true: null is considered empty.

switch ($location) {
    case empty($location) :    // this performs the check:
                               // $location == empty($location)
                               //      null == true ==> false
```

so that's why it doesn't run..

I'd recommend sticking to `if .. else` in this case.

Comment: But there is no problem with    case ($location%10000==0):
expression 2;
    break;
    case ($location%100==0):
expression 3;

Comment: ok, well think it through: `$location = 20000`, therefore `$location % 10000 == 0)` is `true`. `20000 == true` is true, therefore it works. If you really want to stick with this format for some reason change your switch statement to be: `switch (true) {`

Comment: Your answer and comments are very helpful. Thank you, @nickf.

Answer (score 0):

The `empty` function returns a boolean value of 1 or 0 https://www.php.net/empty

Whereas the `switch / case` statements check whether a variable holds a certain value and execute an expression depending on that

In you case, `expression 1` should be executed if the value of `$location==1` (you effectively asked for that when you typed `switch($location)`),

So the logic of your above code is:

> if $location==1, execute expression 1
> if $location%10000==0, execute expression 2
> etc. etc.

is the value of `$location==1`?

Answer (score 0):

A `switch` statement is not the same as an `if/else` statement. Switch statements are looking for specific values. If it finds the value specified in a given `case` statement, it runs the code after that `case` statement.

The following code:

```
switch($x)
    case 1:
        // some stuff
        break;
    case 2:
        // some other stuff
        break;
    default:
        // some more stuff
        break;
```

Is the equivalent of this code:

```
if($x == 1){
    // some stuff
}
elseif($x == 2){
    // some other stuff
}
else{
    // some more stuff
}
```

Basically, `switch` statements are shortcuts for `if/elseif/else` blocks where you're checking for a single variable's equality against a bunch of possibilities.

Since `empty()` returns 0 or 1, your first `case` will run if `$location` is 1 (if `$location` is empty) or 0 (if `$location` isn't empty). It's almost like you've written the following:

```
elseif($location == empty($location)){ ...
```

Make sense? Instead of using a `switch` statement, you probably want the following:

```
if(empty($location)){
    // ...
}
elseif($location % 10000 == 0){
    // ...
}
// ...
```